# How to show only one arrow in my navigation bar?

Tags: html, css, navbar

Hi can i know how do insert a sigle arrow in my navbar instead of it showing like how it is in the picture? may i know what can i do to solve this problem? And also how can i make arrow function as a button when i clicked it, it will go back to the previous page. Thank you in advance.

[image: nav bar]

This is my html code

```
<!DOCTYPE html> 
<html> 
  
<head> 
    <title> 
      How to change navigation bar color in Bootstrap ? 
  </title> 
  
    <!-- Include Bootstrap CSS -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" 
          href= "https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css"> 
  
    <style> 
        /* Modify the background color */ 
          
        .navbar-custom { 
            background-color:#00644C;
        } 
        /* Modify brand and text color */ 
          
        .navbar-custom .navbar-brand, 
        .navbar-custom .navbar-text { 
            color: #FFFFFF;
            background-image: url(image/Vector.png); 
            
        } 
   
    </style> 
</head> 
  
<body> 
    <!-- Navbar text is dark and background is light -->
    <nav class="navbar navbar-custom"> 
        <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">&emsp;&emsp;&emsp;&emsp;&emsp;&emsp;Verification 
      </a> 
    </nav> 
  

</body> 
  
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What about the background-repeat property?

```
.navbar-custom .navbar-brand, 
.navbar-custom .navbar-text { 
     color: #FFFFFF;
     background-image: url(image/Vector.png); 
     background-repeat: no-repeat;
}
```

You might want to add the following as well. It is up to you where you exactly want it:

```
.navbar-custom .navbar-brand, 
.navbar-custom .navbar-text { 
     background-position: center left;
}
```

Generally all background properties

[Background properties](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_background.asp)

Have you considered using [FontAwesome](https://fontawesome.com/) or some other font library? The following would be better:

```
 <nav class="navbar navbar-custom"> 
     <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">
        <i class="fas fa-arrow-left"></i> 
        Verification 
     </a> 
 </nav>
```

Comment: Thank you so much it works perfectly. May i know how can i make it a button and link it to the previous page?

Comment: Would you mind accept it as the right answer? If you want to link to a previous page, you can always use the history back function: onclick="history.back(-1)" https://css-tricks.com/snippets/javascript/go-back-button/